# Video Concatenation results Output with second part Fast farword

Tags: ffmpeg, trim, concatenation

I am Have an issue while concatenation of videos.

**First Trimming chunks from different videos using Following command**

```
val cmd = arrayOf("-ss", start, "-i", inputFile.ts,"-c:v" ,"libx264","-preset" ,"ultrafast","-crf" ,"32", "-tune","fastdecode","-t",
        duration, "-avoid_negative_ts", "make_zero","-fflags","+genpts",
        outPutPath.mp4
    )
```

**Secondly Merging Using Following Command**

```
 val cmd = arrayOf("-f", "concat", "-safe", "0", "-i", data.ts, "-c", "copy", outP.mp4)
```

**This Only happens if videos are of different dimensions.**
Please guide what I am doing wrong here or how to resolve this issue.

**Update**
I came to know you have to scale videos to the same size for achieving the above.I have done as the following command: ** Filter setsar has an unconnected output
Conversion failed!**

```
 var cmd = arrayOf( "-i", listofFiles[0],"-i",listofFiles[1], "-filter_complex",
        "[0]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[0v];[1]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[1v];[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1[v][a]", "-map", "[v]","-map" ,"[a]" ,outP)"
```

Getting Err:

```
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Flory/temp/Trimmed1599124061259.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:05.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1537 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1080x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 1465 kb/s, 24.97 fps, 24.87 tbr, 90k tbn, 49.74 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 70 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Flory/temp/Trimmed1599124064134.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
  Duration: 00:00:03.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16173 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 16279 kb/s, 29.79 fps, 29.58 tbr, 11360 tbn, 59.17 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Filter setsar has an unconnected output
Conversion failed!
```

Please help me I am stuck for a week now.

Comment: All input files must have to same attributes to concat properly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I came to know you have to scale inputs. I have done that. but Audio Streams are not being added to the final video.
I am editing my questions to show what I have done yet.

Comment: @llogan I actually devised the edited question update command from your answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55050410/14052617)

Comment: Also see [How to concatenate videos in ffmpeg with different attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367243/)

Comment: Thank you Once again.
Can you please guide that a video in full-screen portrait mode is reduced to the size of the old Nokia fone screen size, like padding is added to it by this command.

Comment: Should be asked as a new, separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[0v]` and `[1v]` as inputs to the concat filter, not `[0:v]` and `[1:v]`.

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -i input1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[0v];[1]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[1v];[0v][0:a][1v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. It was very helpful.
I have posted a separate question as you directed can you please view [this](https://superuser.com/q/1583595/1214905)
Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

By running the following command :

```
        var cmd = arrayOf( "-i", listofFiles[0],"-i",listofFiles[1],"-max_muxing_queue_size", "9999","-vsync" ,"2" , "-filter_complex",
        "[0]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[0v];[1]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[1v];[0v][0:a][1v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1[outv][outa]", "-map", "[outv]","-map" ,"[outa]","-c:a", "aac","-strict", "-2","-c:v","libx264","-crf" ,"32",outP)
```

This keeps the audio stream in the final output, also scale two inputs equal minimum sized one to avoid stretch.

Not Sure its best solution but Its is at least a Working one.